# Swift - BTLE - How to Add CBCentralManagerDelegate Protocal

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I want to make an ios app that use bluetooth to communicate. I am using swift.

So first I add the CoreBluetooth.framework, then I add a bridge.h and add file to the system bridge, import "CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h".

Then I create a new class,

```
import UIKit

class BTCentral: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate   {

}
```

I am planning to create a bluetooth CBCentralManager in that class. However, the above code gives me an error.

```
Type 'BTCentral' does not conform to protocol 'CBCentralManagerDelegate'
```

Here is a specific ScreenShot: [click here](http://shan.us/Zxgf)

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you guys so much for your time.

Comment: Why import CoreBluetooth through a bridging header? It should be available as a module, so you should just be able to `import CoreBluetooth` in your Swift files. (If that doesn't work you should [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).)

Comment: That works.  @rickster Thank you for your tips. I am still learning developing ios app.

Comment: Sorry for my comment. I wonder why is necessary extend NSObject in this case. If I don't extend NSObject this error continue. Best regards

Comment: @Arubu The delegate for CBCentralManager must be an NSObject. I hope this will get remedied in a future version of CoreBluetooth.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to implement all the methods required by the protocol. In this case, CBCentralManagerDelegate only requires that one method be implemented, `centralManagerDidUpdateState()`.

Add this method to your class and the error will go away.

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager!) {

}
```